# java. moving between rooms, but stuck in one

Tags: java

There is only so long you can look at a problem before you go blind. I have two rooms called A and B and I want to move between them, but no matter what I do I'm stuck in room A (current) and the fail message ("there is no room here") pop up whatever I write.  I'm going to add a bunch of rooms so I cant change the code too much, but on the other hand I don't think I'm to far off. I tried a bunch of things, but did not want to add to much and make a mess of the code before handing it to you. .

To be clear, If I write rightI want the outprint to be you are in room B, and the current to move to B. If I write left I want the output to be "there is no room her and current to stay at room A.

If anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong it would be super helpful.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Totest {
  public static void main (String [] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    TryRoom A = new TryRoom  ("room a","Awesome","Left");
    TryRoom B = new TryRoom ("room b","Bad","Right");
    B.setLeft(A);
    A.setRight(B);

    TryRoom Current;
    Current = A;
    String move;

    while (true) {
      System.out.println(("you are in ") + (Current.getName()));
      System.out.println(("the exit is ") + (Current.getExit()));
      move = keyboard.nextLine();

      if(move.equals("right")){
        if(Current.checkRight()){
          Current = Current.getRight();//problem?
        }else{
          System.out.println("there is no room here");
        }
      }
      if(move.equals("left")){
        if(Current.checkLeft()){//problem?
          Current = Current.getLeft();
        }else{
          System.out.println("There is no room here");
        }
      }
    }//while  
  }
}
```

:::::::::::

```
class TryRoom {
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String exit;
  private TryRoom left;
  private TryRoom right;  

  public TryRoom(String name, String description, String exit)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.exit = exit;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  } 

  public String getDescription(){
    return description;
  } 

  public String getExit(){
    return exit;
  } 

  void setLeft(TryRoom A)
  {this.left=left;}
  public TryRoom getLeft() 
  {return left;}

  void setRight(TryRoom B)
  {this.right=right;}
  public TryRoom getRight() 
  {return right;}

  boolean checkRight(){ 
    if (this.right==null){
      return false;}
    else{
      return true;}
  }

  boolean checkLeft(){
    if (this.left==null){
      return false;}
    else{
      return true;}
  }
}
```

Comment: _To be clear, If I write left I want the outprint to be you are in room B, and the current to move to B. If I write left I want the output to be "there is no room her and current to stay at room A._ You are writing 'left' both times and expecting different results? To be clear, this line is the most unclear in your explanation.

Comment: Please fix the typo "her" > "here" everywhere, or I'm gonna go blind too XD

Comment: fixing typos now :) and as for the left x2, Im sure you would know what I ment if you had tried

Comment: Just as a recommendation take a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367 with regards to variable naming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in your setter :

```
void setLeft(TryRoom A)
{this.left=A;}
```

idem for setRight() method

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have got it in `setLeft` and `setRight` methods. Try to change it this way:

```
void setLeft(TryRoom A)
  {this.left=A;}

void setRight(TryRoom B)
  {this.right=B;}
```